# Excel diagram type for x-y-value datas or better tooling

Tags: microsoft-excel, diagrams

To visual my calculation values I create debug csv-files with following structure:

> x;y;value

```
| x       | y       | res value1  | result value2  |
|---------|---------|-------------|----------------|
| -0.0500 | -0.0500 | -48746.6934 | -12185006.6746 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0450 | -48518.2139 | -12172120.4327 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0400 | -48289.7344 | -12159234.1909 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0350 | -48061.2550 | -12146347.9490 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0300 | -47832.7755 | -12133461.7071 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0250 | -47604.2960 | -12120575.4653 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0200 | -47375.8166 | -12107689.2234 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0150 | -47147.3371 | -12094802.9815 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0100 | -46918.8576 | -12081916.7397 |
| -0.0500 | -0.0050 | -46690.3782 | -12069030.4978 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0000  | -46452.7320 | -12056117.1726 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0050  | -7396.7654  | -10878601.5957 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0100  | -2376.1024  | -10720080.9840 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0150  | -2105.1354  | -10702854.9401 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0200  | -1840.9101  | -10685264.4170 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0250  | -1581.0432  | -10667460.0813 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0300  | -1325.2512  | -10649691.6832 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0350  | -1072.2842  | -10631954.5976 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0400  | -822.6089   | -10614503.6578 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0450  | -574.8753   | -10597180.6139 |
| -0.0500 | 0.0500  | -328.3333   | -122912.5000   |
| -0.0450 | -0.0500 | -48518.2139 | -12083653.1836 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0450 | -48289.7344 | -12070766.9417 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0400 | -48061.2550 | -12057880.6999 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0350 | -47832.7755 | -12044994.4580 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0300 | -47604.2960 | -12032108.2161 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0250 | -47375.8166 | -12019221.9743 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0200 | -47147.3371 | -12006335.7324 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0150 | -46918.8576 | -11993449.4905 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0100 | -46690.3782 | -11980563.2487 |
| -0.0450 | -0.0050 | -46461.8987 | -11967677.0068 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0000  | -46223.2942 | -11954755.6608 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0050  | -4159.0866  | -10686818.5098 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0100  | -2136.6813  | -10617737.6805 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0150  | -1863.1435  | -10599835.2512 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0200  | -1597.1223  | -10581602.8635 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0250  | -1336.2345  | -10563253.2258 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0300  | -1079.0842  | -10544879.7235 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0350  | -826.4923   | -10526896.7837 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0400  | -575.8753   | -10508951.5314 |
| -0.0450 | 0.0450  | -327.9167   | -122806.9583   |
| -0.0450 | 0.0500  | -82.8330    | -10474139.0060 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0500 | -48289.7344 | -11982299.6926 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0450 | -48061.2550 | -11969413.4508 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0400 | -47832.7755 | -11956527.2089 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0350 | -47604.2960 | -11943640.9670 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0300 | -47375.8166 | -11930754.7252 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0250 | -47147.3371 | -11917868.4833 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0200 | -46918.8576 | -11904982.2414 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0150 | -46690.3782 | -11892095.9996 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0100 | -46461.8987 | -11879209.7577 |
| -0.0400 | -0.0050 | -46233.4192 | -11866323.5158 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0000  | -45993.6064 | -11853390.6073 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0050  | -2181.9646  | -10532775.4731 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0100  | -1895.0435  | -10515074.5854 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0150  | -1619.2098  | -10496405.4581 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0200  | -1351.0512  | -10477379.6850 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0250  | -1089.0301  | -10458382.2973 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0300  | -831.4589   | -10439513.4512 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0350  | -578.2711   | -10421045.9802 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0400  | -327.3333   | -122658.6667   |
| -0.0400 | 0.0450  | -79.7289    | -10384849.8715 |
| -0.0400 | 0.0500  | 165.3756    | -10367430.3588 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0500 | -48061.2550 | -11880946.2016 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0450 | -47832.7755 | -11868059.9598 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0400 | -47604.2960 | -11855173.7179 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0350 | -47375.8166 | -11842287.4760 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0300 | -47147.3371 | -11829401.2342 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0250 | -46918.8576 | -11816514.9923 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0200 | -46690.3782 | -11803628.7504 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0150 | -46461.8987 | -11790742.5086 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0100 | -46233.4192 | -11777856.2667 |
| -0.0350 | -0.0050 | -46004.9398 | -11764970.0248 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0000  | -45023.8870 | -11729829.3453 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0050  | -1943.2101  | -10430753.5862 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0100  | -1651.0390  | -10412005.0735 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0150  | -1371.4179  | -10392209.8525 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0200  | -1101.7134  | -10372322.4231 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0250  | -838.5589   | -10352561.7854 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0300  | -580.5378   | -10333109.3977 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0350  | -326.5833   | -122467.6250   |
| -0.0350 | 0.0400  | -76.8330    | -10295605.4661 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0450  | 170.8256    | -10277432.4846 |
| -0.0350 | 0.0500  | 416.1801    | -10259665.9303 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0500 | -47832.7755 | -11779592.7106 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0450 | -47604.2960 | -11766706.4688 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0400 | -47375.8166 | -11753820.2269 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0350 | -47147.3371 | -11740933.9850 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0300 | -46918.8576 | -11728047.7432 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0250 | -46690.3782 | -11715161.5013 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0200 | -46461.8987 | -11702275.2594 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0150 | -46233.4192 | -11689389.0176 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0100 | -46004.9398 | -11676502.7757 |
| -0.0300 | -0.0050 | -45776.4603 | -11663616.5338 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0000  | -41791.0999 | -11538381.7385 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0050  | -1701.1682  | -10328399.1057 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0100  | -1402.5845  | -10308181.3534 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0150  | -1120.0801  | -10287125.8407 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0200  | -847.7923   | -10266011.7863 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0250  | -584.1878   | -10245484.1903 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0300  | -325.6000   | -122216.3333   |
| -0.0300 | 0.0350  | -72.2997    | -10205911.2170 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0400  | 177.7089    | -10186999.1939 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0450  | 425.1259    | -10168525.1082 |
| -0.0300 | 0.0500  | 669.2512    | -10150816.0851 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0500 | -47604.2960 | -11678239.2196 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0450 | -47375.8166 | -11665352.9778 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0400 | -47147.3371 | -11652466.7359 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0350 | -46918.8576 | -11639580.4940 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0300 | -46690.3782 | -11626694.2522 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0250 | -46461.8987 | -11613808.0103 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0200 | -46233.4192 | -11600921.7684 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0150 | -46004.9398 | -11588035.5266 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0100 | -45776.4603 | -11575149.2847 |
| -0.0250 | -0.0050 | -45547.9808 | -11562263.0428 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0000  | -38557.4669 | -11346914.7255 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0050  | -1454.7179  | -10225503.7709 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0100  | -1149.0259  | -10203296.7895 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0150  | -862.6256   | -10180482.4539 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0200  | -589.0878   | -10158132.2745 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0250  | -324.1667   | -121847.9167   |
| -0.0250 | 0.0300  | -66.6289    | -10115885.6241 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0350  | 186.4923    | -10095968.8197 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0400  | 435.6926    | -10076817.0674 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0450  | 682.0845    | -10058256.5860 |
| -0.0250 | 0.0500  | 925.9390    | -10040305.9483 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0500 | -47375.8166 | -11576885.7287 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0450 | -47147.3371 | -11563999.4868 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0400 | -46918.8576 | -11551113.2449 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0350 | -46690.3782 | -11538227.0031 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0300 | -46461.8987 | -11525340.7612 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0250 | -46233.4192 | -11512454.5193 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0200 | -46004.9398 | -11499568.2775 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0150 | -45776.4603 | -11486682.0356 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0100 | -45547.9808 | -11473795.7937 |
| -0.0200 | -0.0050 | -45319.5014 | -11460909.5519 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0000  | -35322.3506 | -11155405.6708 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0050  | -1200.8551  | -10121560.4049 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0100  | -886.6423   | -10096422.5797 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0150  | -596.6836   | -10071357.1400 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0200  | -322.0000   | -121286.6667   |
| -0.0200 | 0.0250  | -58.0622    | -10025018.8750 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0300  | 199.4589    | -10003615.6539 |
| -0.0200 | 0.0350  | 450.9634    | -9983522.2246  |
| -0.0200 | 0.0400  | 698.9845    | -9964209.2535  |
| -0.0200 | 0.0450  | 944.0848    | -9945632.5846  |
| -0.0200 | 0.0500  | 1186.5601   | -9927791.8948  |
| -0.0150 | -0.0500 | -47147.3371 | -11475532.2377 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0450 | -46918.8576 | -11462645.9958 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0400 | -46690.3782 | -11449759.7539 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0350 | -46461.8987 | -11436873.5121 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0300 | -46233.4192 | -11423987.2702 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0250 | -46004.9398 | -11411101.0283 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0200 | -45776.4603 | -11398214.7865 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0150 | -45547.9808 | -11385328.5446 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0100 | -45319.5014 | -11372442.3027 |
| -0.0150 | -0.0050 | -45091.0219 | -11359556.0609 |
| -0.0150 | 0.0000  | -32084.2718 | -10963788.0015 |
| -0.0150 | 0.0050  | -934.6256   | -10015451.2889 |
| -0.0150 | 0.0100  | -610.5628   | -9985862.3387  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0150  | -318.3500   | -120329.2083   |
| -0.0150 | 0.0200  | -44.4789    | -9932633.5008  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0250  | 217.9589    | -9909377.9881  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0300  | 473.0009    | -9887778.6734  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0350  | 723.0845    | -9867417.5877  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0400  | 968.5890    | -9848389.4917  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0450  | 1211.9435   | -9829963.5207  |
| -0.0150 | 0.0500  | 1452.5479   | -9812435.6746  |
| -0.0100 | -0.0500 | -46918.8576 | -11374178.7467 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0450 | -46690.3782 | -11361292.5048 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0400 | -46461.8987 | -11348406.2629 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0350 | -46233.4192 | -11335520.0211 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0300 | -46004.9398 | -11322633.7792 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0250 | -45776.4603 | -11309747.5373 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0200 | -45547.9808 | -11296861.2955 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0150 | -45319.5014 | -11283975.0536 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0100 | -45091.0219 | -11271088.8117 |
| -0.0100 | -0.0050 | -44862.5424 | -11258202.5699 |
| -0.0100 | 0.0000  | -28838.7846 | -10771787.5614 |
| -0.0100 | 0.0050  | -643.3211   | -9903794.8605  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0100  | -311.0000   | -118355.8333   |
| -0.0100 | 0.0150  | -20.2705    | -9836830.9392  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0200  | 249.4923    | -9810484.5724  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0250  | 507.5676    | -9787161.9659  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0300  | 758.5845    | -9765889.0886  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0350  | 1004.1057   | -9746403.7843  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0400  | 1246.7101   | -9727886.1882  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0450  | 1486.2479   | -9710482.9255  |
| -0.0100 | 0.0500  | 1724.0357   | -9693724.6212  |
| -0.0050 | -0.0500 | -46690.3782 | -11272825.2557 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0450 | -46461.8987 | -11259939.0138 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0400 | -46233.4192 | -11247052.7719 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0350 | -46004.9398 | -11234166.5301 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0300 | -45776.4603 | -11221280.2882 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0250 | -45547.9808 | -11208394.0463 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0200 | -45319.5014 | -11195507.8045 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0150 | -45091.0219 | -11182621.5626 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0100 | -44862.5424 | -11169735.3208 |
| -0.0050 | -0.0050 | -44634.0630 | -11156849.0789 |
| -0.0050 | 0.0000  | -25563.6683 | -10577145.1733 |
| -0.0050 | 0.0050  | -288.8333   | -112036.2500   |
| -0.0050 | 0.0100  | 35.8586     | -9729621.7005  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0150  | 312.6256    | -9698888.4899  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0200  | 570.0217    | -9674466.2064  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0250  | 817.5679    | -9653624.2145  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0300  | 1059.8098   | -9634825.3997  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0350  | 1298.5435   | -9617440.1891  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0400  | 1535.2521   | -9600887.3326  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0450  | 3510.7532   | -8767025.2325  |
| -0.0050 | 0.0500  | 6746.5779   | -7340758.3188  |
| 0.0000  | -0.0500 | -46452.7320 | -11166961.3480 |
| 0.0000  | -0.0450 | -46223.2942 | -11153608.7520 |
| 0.0000  | -0.0400 | -45993.6064 | -11140135.9476 |
| 0.0000  | -0.0350 | -45023.8870 | -10778845.3215 |
| 0.0000  | -0.0300 | -41791.0999 | -9353909.7932  |
| 0.0000  | -0.0250 | -38557.4669 | -7928574.9836  |
| 0.0000  | -0.0200 | -35322.3506 | -6502547.9657  |
| 0.0000  | -0.0150 | -32084.2718 | -5075163.1249  |
| 0.0000  | -0.0100 | -28838.7846 | -3644493.9299  |
| 0.0000  | -0.0050 | -25563.6683 | -2201800.2453  |
| 0.0000  | 0.0000  | 0.0000      | 0.0000         |
| 0.0000  | 0.0050  | 24985.9183  | 2076586.2870   |
| 0.0000  | 0.0100  | 28216.6180  | 3500516.0132   |
| 0.0000  | 0.0150  | 31447.3176  | 4924445.7395   |
| 0.0000  | 0.0200  | 34678.0173  | 6348375.4657   |
| 0.0000  | 0.0250  | 37908.7169  | 7772305.1919   |
| 0.0000  | 0.0300  | 41139.4166  | 9196234.9182   |
| 0.0000  | 0.0350  | 44370.1162  | 10620164.6444  |
| 0.0000  | 0.0400  | 45338.2731  | 10980699.2810  |
| 0.0000  | 0.0450  | 45566.7526  | 10993585.5228  |
| 0.0000  | 0.0500  | 45795.2320  | 11006471.7647  |
| 0.0050  | -0.0500 | -7396.7654  | 7183207.9751   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0450 | -4159.0866  | 8610229.3992   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0400 | -2181.9646  | 9444706.2181   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0350 | -1943.2101  | 9462010.1891   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0300 | -1701.1682  | 9480608.8789   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0250 | -1454.7179  | 9500848.8395   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0200 | -1200.8551  | 9523709.9564   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0150 | -934.6256   | 9550526.8232   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0100 | -643.3211   | 9584208.5026   |
| 0.0050  | -0.0050 | -288.8333   | -30936.2500    |
| 0.0050  | 0.0000  | 24985.9183  | 10416372.8816  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0050  | 43967.3963  | 10991849.0789  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0100  | 44195.8758  | 11004735.3208  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0150  | 44424.3552  | 11017621.5626  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0200  | 44652.8347  | 11030507.8045  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0250  | 44881.3142  | 11043394.0463  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0300  | 45109.7936  | 11056280.2882  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0350  | 45338.2731  | 11069166.5301  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0400  | 45566.7526  | 11082052.7719  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0450  | 45795.2320  | 11094939.0138  |
| 0.0050  | 0.0500  | 46023.7115  | 11107825.2557  |
| 0.0100  | -0.0500 | -2376.1024  | 9534771.1212   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0450 | -2136.6813  | 9552083.6755   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0400 | -1895.0435  | 9570173.6882   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0350 | -1651.0390  | 9589028.7843   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0300 | -1402.5845  | 9609332.4220   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0250 | -1149.0259  | 9631101.7784   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0200 | -886.6423   | 9655249.8640   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0150 | -610.5628   | 9682491.3559   |
| 0.0100  | -0.0100 | -311.0000   | -35589.1667    |
| 0.0100  | -0.0050 | 35.8586     | 9748514.1209   |
| 0.0100  | 0.0000  | 28216.6180  | 10607792.9780  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0050  | 44195.8758  | 11093202.5699  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0100  | 44424.3552  | 11106088.8117  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0150  | 44652.8347  | 11118975.0536  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0200  | 44881.3142  | 11131861.2955  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0250  | 45109.7936  | 11144747.5373  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0300  | 45338.2731  | 11157633.7792  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0350  | 45566.7526  | 11170520.0211  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0400  | 45795.2320  | 11183406.2629  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0450  | 46023.7115  | 11196292.5048  |
| 0.0100  | 0.0500  | 46252.1910  | 11209178.7467  |
| 0.0150  | -0.0500 | -2105.1354  | 9652816.1226   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0450 | -1863.1435  | 9670724.8540   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0400 | -1619.2098  | 9689184.6063   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0350 | -1371.4179  | 9708788.4211   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0300 | -1120.0801  | 9729259.0171   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0250 | -862.6256   | 9751197.9881   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0200 | -596.6836   | 9774856.3446   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0150 | -318.3500   | -37254.0417    |
| 0.0150  | -0.0100 | -20.2705    | 9827939.4221   |
| 0.0150  | -0.0050 | 312.6256    | 9855922.9556   |
| 0.0150  | 0.0000  | 31447.3176  | 10799213.0744  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0050  | 44424.3552  | 11194556.0609  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0100  | 44652.8347  | 11207442.3027  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0150  | 44881.3142  | 11220328.5446  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0200  | 45109.7936  | 11233214.7865  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0250  | 45338.2731  | 11246101.0283  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0300  | 45566.7526  | 11258987.2702  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0350  | 45795.2320  | 11271873.5121  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0400  | 46023.7115  | 11284759.7539  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0450  | 46252.1910  | 11297645.9958  |
| 0.0150  | 0.0500  | 46480.6704  | 11310532.2377  |
| 0.0200  | -0.0500 | -1840.9101  | 9767159.5198   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0450 | -1597.1223  | 9785315.3242   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0400 | -1351.0512  | 9804039.7535   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0350 | -1101.7134  | 9823547.0996   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0300 | -847.7923   | 9844069.8206   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0250 | -589.0878   | 9865391.4166   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0200 | -322.0000   | -38103.3333    |
| 0.0200  | -0.0150 | -44.4789    | 9911758.8587   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0100 | 249.4923    | 9936268.0381   |
| 0.0200  | -0.0050 | 570.0217    | 9960054.1549   |
| 0.0200  | 0.0000  | 34678.0173  | 10990633.1708  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0050  | 44652.8347  | 11295909.5519  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0100  | 44881.3142  | 11308795.7937  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0150  | 45109.7936  | 11321682.0356  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0200  | 45338.2731  | 11334568.2775  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0250  | 45566.7526  | 11347454.5193  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0300  | 45795.2320  | 11360340.7612  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0350  | 46023.7115  | 11373227.0031  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0400  | 46252.1910  | 11386113.2449  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0450  | 46480.6704  | 11398999.4868  |
| 0.0200  | 0.0500  | 46709.1499  | 11411885.7287  |
| 0.0250  | -0.0500 | -1581.0432  | 9879131.7295   |
| 0.0250  | -0.0450 | -1336.2345  | 9897247.5443   |
| 0.0250  | -0.0400 | -1089.0301  | 9915885.2237   |
| 0.0250  | -0.0350 | -838.5589   | 9935190.3197   |
| 0.0250  | -0.0300 | -584.1878   | 9955168.8324   |
| 0.0250  | -0.0250 | -324.1667   | -38614.5833    |
| 0.0250  | -0.0200 | -58.0622    | 9997420.4828   |
| 0.0250  | -0.0150 | 217.9589    | 10019552.4539  |
| 0.0250  | -0.0100 | 507.5676    | 10041835.1020  |
| 0.0250  | -0.0050 | 817.5679    | 10062889.8959  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0000  | 37908.7169  | 11182053.2671  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0050  | 44881.3142  | 11397263.0428  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0100  | 45109.7936  | 11410149.2847  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0150  | 45338.2731  | 11423035.5266  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0200  | 45566.7526  | 11435921.7684  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0250  | 45795.2320  | 11448808.0103  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0300  | 46023.7115  | 11461694.2522  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0350  | 46252.1910  | 11474580.4940  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0400  | 46480.6704  | 11487466.7359  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0450  | 46709.1499  | 11500352.9778  |
| 0.0250  | 0.0500  | 46937.6294  | 11513239.2196  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0500 | -1325.2512  | 9989122.7518   |
| 0.0300  | -0.0450 | -1079.0842  | 10007305.8374  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0400 | -831.4589   | 10025656.4855  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0350 | -580.5378   | 10044600.7899  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0300 | -325.6000   | -38955.6667    |
| 0.0300  | -0.0250 | -66.6289    | 10084046.7320  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0200 | 199.4589    | 10104632.6197  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0150 | 473.0009    | 10125341.3094  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0100 | 758.5845    | 10145958.0201  |
| 0.0300  | -0.0050 | 1059.8098   | 10165143.2515  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0000  | 41139.4166  | 11373473.3635  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0050  | 45109.7936  | 11498616.5338  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0100  | 45338.2731  | 11511502.7757  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0150  | 45566.7526  | 11524389.0176  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0200  | 45795.2320  | 11537275.2594  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0250  | 46023.7115  | 11550161.5013  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0300  | 46252.1910  | 11563047.7432  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0350  | 46480.6704  | 11575933.9850  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0400  | 46709.1499  | 11588820.2269  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0450  | 46937.6294  | 11601706.4688  |
| 0.0300  | 0.0500  | 47166.1088  | 11614592.7106  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0500 | -1072.2842  | 10097746.7115  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0450 | -826.4923   | 10115498.3180  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0400 | -578.2711   | 10133659.3723  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0350 | -326.5833   | -39191.1250    |
| 0.0350  | -0.0300 | -72.2997    | 10171265.2623  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0250 | 186.4923    | 10190567.2854  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0200 | 450.9634    | 10210176.2981  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0150 | 723.0845    | 10229914.0192  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0100 | 1004.1057   | 10249148.0735  |
| 0.0350  | -0.0050 | 1298.5435   | 10267073.5862  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0000  | 44370.1162  | 11564893.4599  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0050  | 45338.2731  | 11599970.0248  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0100  | 45566.7526  | 11612856.2667  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0150  | 45795.2320  | 11625742.5086  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0200  | 46023.7115  | 11638628.7504  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0250  | 46252.1910  | 11651514.9923  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0300  | 46480.6704  | 11664401.2342  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0350  | 46709.1499  | 11677287.4760  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0400  | 46937.6294  | 11690173.7179  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0450  | 47166.1088  | 11703059.9598  |
| 0.0350  | 0.0500  | 47394.5883  | 11715946.2016  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0500 | -822.6089   | 10205027.4421  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0450 | -575.8753   | 10222750.8611  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0400 | -327.3333   | -39371.3333    |
| 0.0400  | -0.0350 | -76.8330    | 10258715.5115  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0300 | 177.7089    | 10277249.9096  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0250 | 435.6926    | 10295912.0785  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0200 | 698.9845    | 10314776.1850  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0150 | 968.5890    | 10333553.0310  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0100 | 1246.7101   | 10351862.0854  |
| 0.0400  | -0.0050 | 1535.2521   | 10368833.9002  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0000  | 45338.2731  | 11688437.2740  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0050  | 45566.7526  | 11701323.5158  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0100  | 45795.2320  | 11714209.7577  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0150  | 46023.7115  | 11727095.9996  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0200  | 46252.1910  | 11739982.2414  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0250  | 46480.6704  | 11752868.4833  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0300  | 46709.1499  | 11765754.7252  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0350  | 46937.6294  | 11778640.9670  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0400  | 47166.1088  | 11791527.2089  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0450  | 47394.5883  | 11804413.4508  |
| 0.0400  | 0.0500  | 47623.0678  | 11817299.6926  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0500 | -574.8753   | 10311474.9435  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0450 | -327.9167   | -39511.7917    |
| 0.0450  | -0.0400 | -79.7289    | 10346526.4793  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0350 | 170.8256    | 10364275.9504  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0300 | 425.1259    | 10382389.6193  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0250 | 682.0845    | 10400458.0174  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0200 | 944.0848    | 10418666.5614  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0150 | 1211.9435   | 10436729.9178  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0100 | 1486.2479   | 10454172.4305  |
| 0.0450  | -0.0050 | 3510.7532   | 10522689.3431  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0000  | 45566.7526  | 11789790.7649  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0050  | 45795.2320  | 11802677.0068  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0100  | 46023.7115  | 11815563.2487  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0150  | 46252.1910  | 11828449.4905  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0200  | 46480.6704  | 11841335.7324  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0250  | 46709.1499  | 11854221.9743  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0300  | 46937.6294  | 11867108.2161  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0350  | 47166.1088  | 11879994.4580  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0400  | 47394.5883  | 11892880.6999  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0450  | 47623.0678  | 11905766.9417  |
| 0.0450  | 0.0500  | 47851.5472  | 11918653.1836  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0500 | -328.3333   | -39612.5000    |
| 0.0500  | -0.0450 | -82.8330    | 10434279.0514  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0400 | 165.3756    | 10451576.0745  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0350 | 416.1801    | 10469102.2539  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0300 | 669.2512    | 10486665.0166  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0250 | 925.9390    | 10504357.7376  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0200 | 1186.5601   | 10521993.5420  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0150 | 1452.5479   | 10539443.6797  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0100 | 1724.0357   | 10556261.4840  |
| 0.0500  | -0.0050 | 6746.5779   | 10714309.1270  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0000  | 45795.2320  | 11891144.2559  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0050  | 46023.7115  | 11904030.4978  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0100  | 46252.1910  | 11916916.7397  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0150  | 46480.6704  | 11929802.9815  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0200  | 46709.1499  | 11942689.2234  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0250  | 46937.6294  | 11955575.4653  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0300  | 47166.1088  | 11968461.7071  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0350  | 47394.5883  | 11981347.9490  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0400  | 47623.0678  | 11994234.1909  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0450  | 47851.5472  | 12007120.4327  |
| 0.0500  | 0.0500  | 48080.0267  | 12020006.6746  |
```

I can open this file in Excel (2019) without any problem. To check my values I try to add a diagram which shows the 3D-points. But I found no direct useable diagram type in Excel. So I transform my values from x|y|value list (step 1.) to a x/y-value grid (step 2.):

### Excel steps 1, 2 and 3 and the diagram

[image: Excel steps 1, 2 and 3 and the diagram]

It works and I can create a diagram (3.). But I have to do the transformation 1->2 by hand.

Is there a simple way with Excel or another alternative? I need only a good 3D-visualization for debugging purpose.

Thanks in advance for your recommendations!

Comment: You can do your transformation with a pivot table, it's much quicker then doing it manually. (3d chart might not be created from pivot table data, that case you need to copy data to a new location)

Comment: You provided an excellent visualization of your problem. But your screenshot of data is virtually useless for setting up a scenario by someone else. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I add the table values as markdown-code. I provide the screenshot only to provide my goal (step 3.). Now I use Excel to show the nature of the values. But I search better tooling, to search for values (for example rotating, zoom, selecting points by mouse, found important points). I use it only for myself to proof my developed mathematics algorithm for some very special problems.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the '1' table is located in column A-D, and the G4:N4 & H5:H28 is the 'x' and 'y' labels for table '2'. Put this formula at the 1st value cell (H5), and drag till end of table :

`=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(1,INDEX(($G5=$A:$A)*(H$4=$B:$B),0,1),0))`

ref : [multiple criteria index match](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: Your reference source shows an array formula, but your formula isn't that. Will it work without being array formula?

Comment: Yup. [ this a normal formula, not array.. ]

Comment: here is it's [ref](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fexceljet.net%2Fformula%2Findex-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)..

Comment: .. And for the downvoter..  Appreciate if you please highlight should I had not done something right, so I may work my way to improve it. ( :